# Screen in Firefox cannot be copied, printed out or stored

Tags: printing, copy, screen, screenshot, store

I found a site offering learning modules. These modules are said that they cannot be copied, printed out or stored and only shown in Firefox. Q: How have they done this? Does Firefox offer this?

The site is
https://www.akademie-der-naturheilkunde.ch/rund-ums-studium/zulassung-und-kosten.html

The above is found in the text of this site.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods of copy protection that may have been applied; without seeing the content itself it's not possible to say exactly how they've done it.

It is likely to be some JavaScript running on the page that intercepts clicks and keystrokes and prevents them from firing copy/paste functionality. This is not a Firefox specific feature - all modern browsers would support this.  The reason they mention Firefox is probably because their devs used Firefox in development and were too lazy to ensure that it worked cross-browser, however their site probably displays mostly fine in other modern browsers.

Any form of JavaScript based copy protection as I have described is very weak.  Your average power user can easily circumvent this by using F12 developer tools to strip out the JavaScript and get access to the HTML source.  You may have to have developer tools open before you open the page to prevent the F12 keystroke being blocked.  Note, though, that doing this is probably against the site's terms of service.